# Spring Batch Job stop using JobOperator throws NoSuchJobException

Tags: spring-batch, java-17

My controller wants to stop a currently running job, and it works, but also throws a NoSuchJobException, which is frustrating.

## Documentation Spring

Here's the [Spring doc on stopping a Job](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#stoppingAJob).

I'm using Java 17, Spring Boot 3.1.

## Error

Here you can see the Job start and then stop with the error.

```
2023-07-15T09:20:53.036-05:00  INFO 4450 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=importSpeakersJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
2023-07-15T09:20:53.060-05:00  INFO 4450 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [stepSpeakers]
2023-07-15T09:20:53.674-05:00  INFO 4450 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] n.s.B.E.ExcelRowItemProcessor            : Processing: d&b Y-SUB native
2023-07-15T09:20:54.834-05:00  INFO 4450 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] n.s.B.E.ExcelRowItemProcessor            : Persisting transfer function for d&b audiotechnik Y-SUB Y-SUB
2023-07-15T09:20:55.044-05:00  INFO 4450 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] n.subalignercss.Services.BucketService   : Object ExcelSpeakers/SpeakerToImport/JBL.VTX G28.VTX G28.xlsx was deleted from subaligner
2023-07-15T09:20:55.045-05:00  INFO 4450 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] n.s.B.E.ExcelRowItemProcessor            : Processing: d&b audiotechnik J-SUB J-SUB, INFRA Off, HCD On
2023-07-15T09:21:01.445-05:00  WARN 4450 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobOperator      : Cannot find Job object in the job registry. StoppableTasklet#stop() will not be called

org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [importSpeakersJob] was registered
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry.getJob(MapJobRegistry.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
```

## Controller

I'm using the controlJob method to stop the job.

```
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.DTO.AdminDTO;
import org.springframework.batch.core.*;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
@Log4j2
public class AdminController {
    private final Job importSpeakersJob;
    private final Job importLApresets;
    private final Job importMatlabResultsJob;
    private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private final JobExplorer jobExplorer;
    private final JobOperator jobOperator;

    public AdminController(@Qualifier("importSpeakersJob") Job importSpeakersJob,
                           @Qualifier("importLApresets") Job importLApresets,
                           @Qualifier("importMatlabResultsJob") Job importMatlabResultsJob,
                           JobLauncher jobLauncher, JobExplorer jobExplorer, JobOperator jobOperator) {
        this.importSpeakersJob = importSpeakersJob;
        this.importLApresets = importLApresets;
        this.importMatlabResultsJob = importMatlabResultsJob;
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
        this.jobExplorer = jobExplorer;
        this.jobOperator = jobOperator;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String showAdminPage(@ModelAttribute("adminDTO") AdminDTO adminDTO, Model model) {
        if (adminDTO == null) {
            adminDTO = AdminDTO.builder().build();
        }
        try {
            List<JobInstance> jobInstances = null;
            if (!adminDTO.getJobName().isEmpty()) {
                jobInstances = jobExplorer.getJobInstances(adminDTO.getJobName(), 0, 1);
                if (!jobInstances.isEmpty()) {
                    List<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(jobInstances.get(0));
                    JobExecution lastExecution = jobExecutions.get(jobExecutions.size() - 1);
                    String jobName = lastExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName();
                    BatchStatus status = lastExecution.getStatus();

                    adminDTO.setJobName(jobName);
                    adminDTO.setStatus(status);
                }
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            adminDTO.setStatus(BatchStatus.UNKNOWN);
        }
        model.addAttribute("adminDTO", adminDTO);
        return "admin";
    }

    @PostMapping("/controlJob")
    public RedirectView controlJob(@ModelAttribute("adminDTO") AdminDTO adminDTO, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @RequestParam("submit") String submit) {
        try {
            String selectedJob = adminDTO.getSelectedJob();
            JobParameters jobParameters;
            switch (submit) {
                case "start", "restart" -> {
                    jobParameters = "start".equals(submit) ?
                            new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters() :
                            new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();

                    JobExecution jobExecution = switch (selectedJob) {
                        case "importSpeakersJob" -> jobLauncher.run(importSpeakersJob, jobParameters);
                        case "importLApresets" -> jobLauncher.run(importLApresets, jobParameters);
                        case "importMatlabResultsJob" -> jobLauncher.run(importMatlabResultsJob, jobParameters);
                        default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid job name: " + selectedJob);
                    };

                    log.info("Job " + selectedJob + " started with status : " + jobExecution.getStatus());
                    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("success", "Job " + selectedJob + " started with status : " + jobExecution.getStatus() + ". I'll text you when it's done. ");
                }
                case "stop" -> {
                    try {
                        Set<Long> runningExecutions = jobOperator.getRunningExecutions(selectedJob);
                        if (!runningExecutions.isEmpty()) {
                            jobOperator.stop(runningExecutions.iterator().next());
                            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("success", "Job " + selectedJob + " has been requested to stop.");
                        } else {
                            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "Job " + selectedJob + " is not currently running.");
                        }
                    } catch (NoSuchJobException nsje) {
                        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "No such job: " + selectedJob);
                    }
                }
                default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid action: " + submit);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Job control operation failed.", e);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "Job control operation failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("adminDTO", adminDTO);

        return new RedirectView("/admin");
    }
}
```

## Batch Config

Here I'm configuring each of the jobs.

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.BatchProcessing.BatchDTO.TableSectionFlattened;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.BatchProcessing.BatchDTO.TableSections;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.BatchProcessing.ExcelSpeakers.ExcelRow;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.BatchProcessing.ExcelSpeakers.ExcelRowItemProcessor;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.BatchProcessing.ExcelSpeakers.NamedByteArrayResource;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.BatchProcessing.MatlabResults.ResultRow;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.BatchProcessing.MatlabResults.ResultRowItemProcessor;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.Models.Enums.SortType;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.Models.PreAlignment;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.Models.Speaker;
import nathanlively.subalignercss.Services.BucketService;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobRegistry;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.extensions.excel.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.extensions.excel.mapping.BeanWrapperRowMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.extensions.excel.poi.PoiItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JpaItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator;
import org.springframework.batch.item.json.JacksonJsonObjectReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.json.JsonItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.json.builder.JsonItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JobCompletionNotificationListener listener;

    private final BucketService bucketService;

    @Bean(name = "importLApresets")
    public Job importLApresets(JobRepository jobRepository, Step flattenJsonStep) {
        return new JobBuilder("importLApresets", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(flattenJsonStep)
                .listener(listener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step flattenJsonStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                FlatFileItemWriter<List<TableSectionFlattened>> csvWriter) {
        return new StepBuilder("flattenJsonStep", jobRepository)
                .<TableSections, List<TableSectionFlattened>>chunk(1, transactionManager)
                .reader(readUnflattenedJson())
                .processor(flattenJson())
                .writer(csvWriter)
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public JsonItemReader<TableSections> readUnflattenedJson() {
        return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<TableSections>()
                .name("readUnflattenedJson")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("static/json/la.march2023.json"))
                .jsonObjectReader(new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(TableSections.class))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonFlattenerItemProcessor flattenJson() {
        return new JsonFlattenerItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<List<TableSectionFlattened>> csvWriter() {
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<List<TableSectionFlattened>>()
                .name("csvItemWriter")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("la.march2023.csv"))
                .lineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<>() {
                    {
                        setDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                        setFieldExtractor(list -> {
                            List<String> flattenedStrings = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (TableSectionFlattened flattened : list) {
                                flattenedStrings.add(
                                        "\"" + flattened.getPreset() + "\","
                                                + "\"" + flattened.getDsp() + "\","
                                                + "\"" + flattened.getSource1() + "\","
                                                + "\"" + flattened.getSource2() + "\","
                                                + "\"" + flattened.getSource3() + "\""
                                );
                            }
                            return flattenedStrings.toArray();
                        });
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }





    // Import Excel speakers
    @Bean(name = "importSpeakersJob")
    public Job importSpeakersJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step stepSpeakers) {
        return new JobBuilder("importSpeakersJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(stepSpeakers)
                .listener(listener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepSpeakers(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, JpaItemWriter<Speaker> speakerJpaItemWriter) {
        return new StepBuilder("stepSpeakers", jobRepository)
                .<ExcelRow, Speaker>chunk(1, transactionManager)
                .reader(excelReader())
                .processor(excelRowItemProcessor())
                .writer(speakerJpaItemWriter)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MultiResourceItemReader<ExcelRow> excelReader() {
        List<Resource> resources = loadResources();
        Resource[] resourcesArray = resources.toArray(new Resource[0]);

        PoiItemReader<ExcelRow> reader = createPoiReader();

        return createMultiResourceItemReader(resourcesArray, reader);
    }

    private PoiItemReader<ExcelRow> createPoiReader() {
        PoiItemReader<ExcelRow> reader = new PoiItemReader<>();
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1); // HEADERS
        reader.setRowMapper(rowMapper());
        return reader;
    }

    private MultiResourceItemReader<ExcelRow> createMultiResourceItemReader(Resource[] resourcesArray, PoiItemReader<ExcelRow> reader) {
        MultiResourceItemReader<ExcelRow> multiResourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
        multiResourceItemReader.setResources(resourcesArray);
        multiResourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader);
        return multiResourceItemReader;
    }

    private List<Resource> loadResources() {
        List<Blob> blobs = getBlobs();

        List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Blob blob : blobs) {
            String blobName = blob.getName();
            byte[] content = bucketService.downloadObjectIntoMemory(blobName);
            Path path = Paths.get(blobName);
            String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();
            Resource resource = new NamedByteArrayResource(content, fileName);
            resources.add(resource);
        }
        return resources;
    }

    private List<Blob> getBlobs() {
        List<Blob> blobs = bucketService.listAllFilesInFolder("ExcelSpeakers/SpeakerToImport/", SortType.NAME, ".xlsx");
        List<Blob> finalBlobs = bucketService.listAllFilesInFolder("ExcelSpeakers/FinalSpeakerToImport/", SortType.NAME, ".xlsx");
        blobs.addAll(finalBlobs);
        return blobs;
    }

    @Bean
    public RowMapper<ExcelRow> rowMapper() {
        BeanWrapperRowMapper<ExcelRow> rowMapper = new BeanWrapperRowMapper<>();
        rowMapper.setTargetType(ExcelRow.class);
        return rowMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public ExcelRowItemProcessor excelRowItemProcessor() {
        return new ExcelRowItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaItemWriter<Speaker> speakerJpaItemWriter() {
        return new JpaItemWriterBuilder<Speaker>()
                .entityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory)
                .build();
    }





    // Import MATLAB results
    @Bean(name = "importMatlabResultsJob")
    public Job importMatlabResultsJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step importMATLABResults) {
        return new JobBuilder("importMatlabResultsJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(importMATLABResults)
                .listener(listener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step importMATLABResults(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, JpaItemWriter<PreAlignment> writer) {
        return new StepBuilder("importMATLABResults", jobRepository)
                .<ResultRow, PreAlignment>chunk(1, transactionManager)
                .reader(readMatlabJson())
                .processor(resultRowItemProcessor())
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonItemReader<ResultRow> readMatlabJson() {
        return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<ResultRow>()
                .name("readMatlabJson")
                .jsonObjectReader(new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(ResultRow.class))
                .resource(getJsonFile())
                .build();
    }

    private Resource getJsonFile() {
        List<Blob> blobs = bucketService.listAllFilesInFolder("MATLABresults/", SortType.CREATE_TIME, ".json");
        String objectName = blobs.get(0).getName();
        byte[] content = bucketService.downloadObjectIntoMemory(objectName);
        Path path = Paths.get(objectName);
        String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();
        return new NamedByteArrayResource(content, fileName);
    }

    @Bean
    public ResultRowItemProcessor resultRowItemProcessor() {
        return new ResultRowItemProcessor();
    }


    @Bean
    public JpaItemWriter<PreAlignment> preAlignmentJpaItemWriter() {
        return new JpaItemWriterBuilder<PreAlignment>()
                .entityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PreAlignmentItemProcessor processor() {
        return new PreAlignmentItemProcessor();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default , the `JobRegistry` used by the `JobOperator` does not register any jobs to it and so it cannot find any jobs and throws `NoSuchJobException`.

You can solve this problem by defining [`JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/5.0.2/reference/html/index-single.html#jobregistrybeanpostprocessor) :

```java
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

   @Bean
public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
    JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor postProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
    postProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
    return postProcessor;
} 
}
```

<sub>*P.S. Not sure why the framework does not define it by default as I think it is quite a common thing that will be useful in most applications.*</sub>

Comment: wow, just adding this bean generated about 100 new console logs.

eg. 
```
2023-07-15T17:17:35.988-05:00  INFO 31178 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

Comment: Tested locally. Seems to work. Thanks so much!

Comment: @ken-chan `P.S. Not sure why the framework does not define it by default as I think it is quite a common thing that will be useful in most applications.`: there is feature request for this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4245.